# How to use ilike sqlalchemy on postgresql array field?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to match some names with the names I already have in my Postgresql database, using the following code:

```
last_like = '{last_name}%'.format(last_name)
matches = Session.query(MyTable).filter(or_(
    MyTable.name.ilike(last_like),
    MyTable.other_names.any(last_like, operator=ilike_op),
)).all()
```

Essentially it tries to match the name column *or* any of the other names stored as an array in the other_names column.

But I get:

```
KeyError: <function ilike_op at 0x7fb5269e2500>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For use postgresql array field you need to use `unnest()` function. 
But you can't use result of `unnest()` in `where` clause.

Instead, you can use `array_to_string` function. Searching on string of `other_names` will give the same effect

```
from sqlalchemy import func as F
last_like = "%qq%"
matches = session.query(MyTable).filter(or_(
    MyTable.name.ilike(last_like),
    F.array_to_string(MyTable.other_names, ',').ilike(last_like),
)).all()
```